# Why does the usage of form_tag and form_for change in rails(erb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Old usage:

```
<% form_tag %>
...
<% end %>

<% form_for %>
....
<% end %>
```

New usage:

```
<%= form_tag %>
...
<% end %>

<%= form_for %>
....
<% end %>
```

(I was learning Head First Rails and know the differences in [this list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai2l7E_yOdPMdDN6cHkwZ1hFdjZUYWY1bE9vWnlvN0E#gid=0))

I knew that scriptlet don't need `=` in the `<>`, but if `<%= form_tag %>` is not a scriptlet, why does it need a `<% end %>`?

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I've got no idea what a 'scriplet' is; anyway, this was a change in rails 3.0 - see the release notes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#helpers-with-blocks.

Comment: more formal yet constructive answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 brings overall consistency in the API and in this case in the view API.

Rule is:

```
(want_to_display?) ? (use =) : (don't use =)
```